# is "と” always needed for when saying "with?"

Tags: particles

can I say しごとがんばってね for saying have a nice day at work? do I need the particle と to make it "with work"  しごととがんばってね

Comment: Perhaps it's not, strictly speaking, pertinent to your question, but do you use "with work" that way in English? As in "alongside with" or "together with"? I don't see the connection between "Have a good day with work" and the typical meaning of と when it means "with". The English sentence sounds a little odd to me generally, but I won't go so far as to say it couldn't be said, I guess.

Comment: @Leebo I don't know that you'd usually use "with" in this way in English (I think it could be used, but I struggle to think of an example sentence), but there are certainly languages (such as Norwegian) in which you _would_. For instance, a slightly wobbly translation from Norwegian to English might leave you with "Enjoy yourself with the work.", as an example, which while a bit odd isn't completely out of place.

Answer (score 4):

Japanese がんばる is a **transitive** verb that means "to work hard on/with ～". That is to say, you have to say しごと**を**がんばってね if you don't want to omit particles, but しごとがんばってね is fine in casual conversations, too. しごと**と**がんばってね is ungrammatical.

In general, と meaning *with* cannot be easily omitted like が/は/を. Being able to omit と freely would obviously introduce a lot of confusion and ambiguity. For example, 彼【かれ】映画【えいが】見た【みた】 will always mean "He watched a movie" rather than "I watched a movie with him."